# Live Price monitor

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs, price, websocket, the-graph

How does dexscreener or dextools websites keep up with the price changes efficiently on thousands of tokens? Can anyone provide a sample code for that? if not, then a roadmap of steps to be taken, APIs that could help?